# How do I save multiple pictures as different file names vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to capture images from video screen shot and store them in a file. As the video plays multiple screen shots would we taken and all the picture would be stored in a file. My problem is every time I save my picture it overwrites the previous image captured. Thus leaving me with a single picture at the end instead of a stream of images. I have avoided using show file dialog as I want the picture to be stored automatically.

This code would cause the file A to be over written when the program goes into loop:

```
    Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

I would like to obtain a result like : 
 A1.png,
 A2.png,
 A3.png,
 ...
 An.png

Please do guide me. Thanks
Attached below is my current code:

```
   If mati = 2 Then
   Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
   ElseIf mati = 5 Then
   Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A1.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
   ElseIf mati = 8 Then
   Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A2.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
   ElseIf mati = 11 Then
   Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A3.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
   ElseIf mati = 14 Then
   Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A4.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
   ElseIf mati = 18 Then
   Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A5.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
```

By the way mati is a timer. Is there a proper way for me to create a new file name rather this method?

Comment: Why don't you use the timestamp to name your images?

Comment: Using timestamp would make the stored image harder to be called. As i need call back the captured image for another function. Thus calling image A1.png is easier as it has a fixed name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is overwriting `A.png` because you're giving it the same name again and again.

This is easy to resolve. What you can do is -

- Create a variable to hold click count.

  ```
  /*int count = 1;*/
  Dim count As Integer
  ```
- Update it every time you enter the loop (`count+=1` or as required).
- Add it to your path

  ```
  Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A" & count & ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png
  ```

Done.

**Edit** 
If you already have an loop counter then you can use it, no need to create a new variable (unless you want it persistent, of course ).

**Update**

Sorry, my bad. **&** is used for string concatenation not **+**.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ikmhr, I have tried your code and I'm getting this as an error: Conversion from string "C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A" to type 'Double' is not valid.

Comment: If this solved your problem, please accept the answer (by checking the green tick) to let others know this question is solved.

Comment: Try count.ToString in the Save().

Comment: I updated the answer, please take a look. (replaced `+` with the `&`)

Comment: yeap i did the same as your answer. Even tried to increase the count by:
        Dim count As Integer = 0
        count = count + 1
still the file becomes A1.png and keeps on replacing the file. Once I get the solution i will make sure tick the green tick. By far your answer is the best improvement to my code. thanks a lot Ikmhr

Comment: Did you replace + with &?

Comment: Yes i did.
 Bmp.Save("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A" & count & ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)
I'm guessing my count is not updating.

Comment: Ah, I see. You don't have to create a local variable. It needs to be global and/or static. If you define `count` inside the loop, it will be re-initialized to **1** every time the loop runs. So, the variable should be declared outside the loop and only updated in the loop.

Answer (score -1):

Picturebox save file in different names

Use following code on a button :

```
Static Count As Integer
Count +=1
PictureBox1.Image.Save(("c:\image" & Count.ToString &".jpg"), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
```

Output -- When u click this button then the picbox save the pic in different image names by following path. Thank u.